# Unable to get the elements of an iframe using NightmareJS

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to click on 'a' element inside an iFrame to upload a picture using NightmareJS with [nightmare-iframe-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightmare-iframe-manager) package:

```
  .enterIFrame('iframe[src="http://www.belor.biz/index2.php?option=com_adsmanager&page=multil&stamp=del_9d96f619468e5f5ce15004dba37426f5&ii=1"]')

  .click('a[href="javascript:void(0);"]')
  .insert('input[id=dataurl]', "https://source")
  .click('input[value="Upload!"]')

  .exitIFrame()
```

Code performs well until It get to iframe part and terminal shows:

> Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of null

**What's wrong?**